# Google scripts; Alter Matching function that searches spreadsheet by column, return row of match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-speech-api

I need to alter my Matching function, that matches two columns on separate sheets and returns a
the matches to a third sheet so that it returns the row of the match

I have been trying, my head is spinning, no success

Thanks

```
function RunMatch() {

  // 0 is the LookIn sht column # to match on 
  // 1 is the LookWith sht column # to match on 
  MatchCols("LookInSheet","LookWithSheet","PostbackSheet",0,1)  

}

function MatchCols(sShtName,tShtName,pbShtName,matchIn, matchWith){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var LookInSht = ss.getSheetByName(sShtName);
  var LookWithSht = ss.getSheetByName(tShtName);
  var PBSheet = ss.getSheetByName(pbShtName);

  var LookIn = LookInSht.getDataRange().getValues();
  var LookWith = LookWithSht.getDataRange().getValues();

  var list = [];

  for (i in LookIn){
    var curName = LookIn[i][matchColIn];
    var exists = true;

    for (j in LookWith){
      var curCheck = LookWith[j][matchColWith];
      if (curCheck == curName){
        exists = false;
        break;
      };
    }; // end for j

    list.push([exists ? "" : curName]);

  } // end for i

  PBSheet.getRange(1, PBSheet.getLastColumn() +1, list.length, 1).setValues(list);

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Where do the function's parameters come from?

Comment: When I run the code I get a column of the `matched` elements on the row of the match posted back to the `postback sheet`.  I set the parameters.  I updated the question with how I call the function

Comment: I understand what your code is doing, but I don't understand what you want it to do. Instead of creating a column in the `PostbackSheet` with the matched values, you want it to create a column with the number of row that matched or both values?

Comment: No, I want it to post back the entire row of cells where a match is found, not just the matched cell

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `PostbackSheet` to contain the entire row from `LookIn` when the value in the `matchColIn` column of `LookIn` is found in the `matchColWith` column of `LookWith`.

Instead of using `exists`, just add the row to `list` when you find the match:

```
if (curCheck == curName){
  list.push(LookIn[i]);
  break;
}
```

Then, when you write to `PBSheet`, use the size of list to make sure the range is the correct size:

```
PBSheet.getRange(1, PBSheet.getLastColumn() +1, list.length, list[0].length).setValues(list);
```

Comment: Tiffany, that almost gets me there!. But I need to `postback` the rows on the rows the matches were found in `LookWith` So if a match occurred on row 5 of LookWith the  postback of the entire row in`PostbackSheet` would be on row 5.  I think that is what `list.push([exists ? "" : curName]);` was doing posting pack on the row the match was found on (I think).  Can you show me how to do this last part?.  I tried mixing codes but no success!  Thanks

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to create a second array `var rowNum = []` right after you define `list`. Then, after `list.push(LookIn[i])`, do `rowNum.push(j)`. You could then do a loop through `var k=0; k<rowNum.length; k++` and do `PBSheet.getRange(rowNum[k]+1, PGSheet.getLastColumn()+1, 1, list[0].length).setValues([list[k]])`.

Comment: Tim, if that works for you, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Tiffany, thanks!, it is late here, I will test it first thing in the morning and let you know

Comment: Sorry for the many comments but I missed my 5-minute edit window. The above suggestion is the same as writing to `PBSheet` using row `j+1` each time you find a match, so instead of `list.push()` you just write the row  `LookIn[i]` to `PBSheet`. It's not elegant since you're invoking `setValues()` as many times as matches you have, but it will work.

Comment: Tiffany, I tried your suggestion and it did post back the data but it adds `9 empty rows` between each row posted back

Comment: In `LookWith` sheet there are `9 rows` that have `no` matches to the column in`LookIn` sheet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120463/discussion-between-tiffany-g-wilson-and-tim).